An exercise about regular complex Borel measures and weak$^*$ compactness
Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space. Denote by $\mathcal{M}(K)$ the Banach space of regular complex Borel measures on $K$, and by $\mathcal{P}(K)$ the subset of $\mathcal{M}(K)$ consisting of probability measures (i.e., positive measures such that $\mu(K) = 1$).
Prove that $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K)$ if and only if $\mu(K) = 1$ and $\|\mu\| = 1$. As a consequence, prove that $\mathcal{P}(K)$ is $w^*$-closed and hence $w^*$-compact.
My attempt
It is clear that if $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K)$, then $\mu$ is a positive measure satisfying $\mu(K) = 1$ and $\|\mu\| = |\mu|(K) = \mu(K) = 1$. Let us prove the converse. Suppose $\mu \in \mathcal{M}(K)$ satisfies $\mu(K) = 1$ and $\|\mu\| = 1$. We want to show that it is a probability measure. We already have $\mu(K) = 1$, but
1) how do I prove positivity knowing  $\|\mu\| = 1$?
Let us now prove that $\mathcal{P}(K)$ is $w^*$-closed. Using the Riesz Representation Theorem we can identify $\mathcal{M}(K)$ with $C(K, \mathbb{C})^*$ by associating each measure $\mu$ with the functional $\Lambda_{\mu}$ defined by
$$
   \Lambda_{\mu}(f) = \int_K f \, d\mu, \quad f \in C(K, \mathbb{C}).
$$
We are considering then the space $(\mathcal{M}(K), \sigma(\mathcal{M}(K), C(K, \mathbb{C})))$, with the weak$^*$ topology. Let  $(\mu_n)$ be a sequence of measures in $\mathcal{P}(K)$ such that $\lim \mu_n = \mu$ in the $w^*$-topology. That means that, for every $f \in C(K, \mathbb{C})$,
$$
  \int_K f \, d\mu_n \to \int_K f \, d\mu.
$$
We aim to show that $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K)$. First, note that $\mu(K) = 1$ because, for $f = 1$, we have
$$
  \int_K 1 \, d\mu_n = \mu_n(K) \to \int_K 1 \, d\mu = \mu(K),
$$
and since $\mu_n(K) = 1$, it follows that $\mu(K) = 1$ as $n \to \infty$.
Next, let us verify that $\|\mu\| = 1$. On the one hand, $\|\mu\| = |\mu|(K) \geq |\mu(K)| = 1$, so $\|\mu\| \geq 1$. On the other hand, we show that $\|\mu\| \leq 1$. We know
$$
   |\langle \mu_n, f \rangle| = \left| \int_K f \, d\mu_n \right| \leq \int_K |f| \, d|\mu_n| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \, |\mu_n|(K) = \|f\|_{\infty} \|\mu_n\|,
$$
and taking the limit, since $|\langle \mu_n, f \rangle| \to |\langle \mu, f \rangle|$, we have
$$
  |\langle \mu, f \rangle| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \liminf \|\mu_n\|,
$$
which implies
$$
  \|\mu\| = \sup_{\|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1} |\langle \mu, f \rangle| \leq \liminf \|\mu_n\|.
$$
Therefore,
$$
  \|\mu\| \leq \liminf \|\mu_n\| = 1.
$$
2) Is everything correct in what I wrote above?
Finally, let us show that $\mathcal{P}(K)$ is $w^*$-compact. If $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K)$, then $\|\mu\| = 1$. Hence, $\mathcal{P}(K)$ is a norm-bounded set. This implies that $\mathcal{P}(K) \subset M B_{C(K, \mathbb{C})^*}$ for some $M > 0$, where $B_{C(K, \mathbb{C})^*}$ denotes the closed unit ball of $C(K, \mathbb{C})^*$, which is $w^*$-compact by the Alaoglu Theorem. We use that a $w^*$-closed in a $w^*$-compact set is a $w^*$-compact set.
3) Is this correct?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.


If $\mu$ is a finite measure on any set $A$ (i.e. on a sigma-algebra with maximal element $A$) such that $|\mu(A)| = |\mu|(A)$, then $\mu$ is a positive measure multiplied by a complex constant. We can consider the case $\mu(A) \ne 0$. Indeed, if there is a subset $B \subset A$ in the domain of $\mu$ such that $\mu(B) \notin \mu(A)[0, +\infty)$, then $|\mu|(A) = |\mu|(B) + |\mu|(A \setminus B) \ge |\mu(B)| + |\mu(A \setminus B)| > |\mu(A)|$. The last inequality is strict since the arguments of complex numbers $\mu(B)$ and $\mu(A \setminus B)$ do not coincide. Thus, we proved that if all values of a measure $\mu$ do not have the same argument as complex numbers, then we have a strict inequality $|\mu|(A) > |\mu(A)|$.

Everything is correct, besides that I doubt that it is possible to conclude closedness of a subset of a weak dual of a Banach space by considering convergent sequences (i.e. sequential closedness does not imply topological closedness). Maybe in this case it suffices due to some additional arguments with compactness and Eberlein-Smulian theorem, but I rather recommend to replace sequences with nets, since it definitely suffices for closedness and your argument won't need any additional work.

Everything is ok here.




So I would use in my case that $\mu(K)=1$ and get the wanted result, right? You write that the complex constant is the measure of the maximal element and the arguments of complex numbers $\mu(B)$ and $\mu(A∖B)$ do not coincide by hypothesis, correct? Isn't there a direct proof instead of applying a more general result, just wondering?



There is something that still confuses me about the identification $C(K, \mathbb{C})^$ and $\mathcal{M}(K)$. When I write $\mathcal{P}(K) \subset M B_{C(K,\mathbb{C})^}$, this is an abuse of notation, we really mean  $\mathcal{P}(K) \subset M B_{\mathcal{M}(K)}$. So how can I relate $^$compactness in  $ M B_{C(K, \mathbb{C})^}$ with $^*$compactness in $M B_{\mathcal{M}(K)}$? This is just because of the identification, correct?

